# Set a button fade out with js before loading a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm still a noob in .js but trying to do my thing here ;)
I want the "pausebutton" to fade out when the video is paused. Till now its always visible, so I guess I have to tell this little guy to be faded out in the beginning so I can $(this).children(".pauseicon").fadeIn(); after that. I used jquery and some js for that.
Any Ideas?

```
$('.video').parent().click(function () {
if($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused){
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
    $(this).children(".playicon").fadeOut();
}else{
   $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
    $(this).children(".pauseicon").fadeIn();
}
```

});

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kurbelklaus/L2ddxcqr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2ddxcqr/2/). I hide the pause button initially and then also faded out the pause button on every click.

```
$(".pauseicon").hide();
$('.video').parent().click(function () {
    if($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused){
        $(this).children(".pauseicon").fadeOut();
        $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
        $(this).children(".playicon").fadeOut();
    }else{
        $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
        $(this).children(".pauseicon").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Master!! @Loaf